# Proof that $\nabla f(x) = \nabla f(y)$ if and only if $x = y$

Tags: convex-analysis

Trying to tackling a convexity problem. Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued differentiable function on $R^n$. If $f(x)$ is strictly convex, prove that $\nabla f(x) = \nabla f(y)$ if and only if $x = y$.

Comment: This is equivalent to the same property for $n = 1$, since it will be true of $f$ restricted to the line through $x$ and $y$.